# Moodle Database API - $DB is an object of abstract class

Tags: php, moodle

I am new to `PHP` and has started with `Moodle`. In Moodle I found that there is a global object `$DB`, instance of `moodle_database` class. I found that `moodle_database` is an abstract class. And various functions of `moodle_database` are abstract as well.

```
global $DB;
$DB = new moodle_database();
```

And `moodle_database`:

```
abstract class moodle_database
```

How is it possible to create an instance of abstract class? Even if `moodle_database` was extended by some other class and $DB was an object of that class, things can be assumed to be simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lib/setup.php, there is a call to setup_DB(), which is defined in lib/dmllib.php.

This, in turn, calls $DB = moodle_database::get_driver_instance() which instantiates a subclass of moodle_database.

I don't know exactly where the line of code you refer to its found, but I suspect that it will never actually be run and is simply there to provide type hinting to IDEs, so auto completion will work when writing moodle code.